# Can a Kohen come in contact with any corpse in order to reach a Meis Mitzvah?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

If there is a Meis Mitzvah, and the only way to get to it is by becoming impure by another corpse - not a Meis Mitzvah - is a Kohen allowed to do so?

Comment: For a relative that he must become tameh for, he can’t do that. See SA YD 373:7. as to whether a meis mitzvah is different, is a good question